# How do I print nextflow script parameters in arparse style?

Tags: command-line-interface, argparse, nextflow

I would like to print the parameters of my nextflow script as a help menu (e.g., `nextflow run main.nf --help`), similar to the way arparse does it in python (i.e., `script --help`).

I have trawled the web and help docs and have found how to print a custom menu using the `log.info` command inside the script, but this only shows the custom log stdout when actually running the script.

My workaround is to grep the script as follows: `grep -E '^params.+ +\=' main.nf`.
This provides me with something similar to:

```
params.publishdir        = '$TMPDIR'
params.min.              = 3
```

It would be great if `nextflow run main.nf --help` gave me a similar output (even better if `'$TMPDIR'` was expanded), but `--help` is basically feeding the run `params.help`; and `nextflow run main.nf -h` gives me the top level program help, neither of which, ahem, *help*. Is there a nextflow builtin to solve this?

Comment: `argparse` has a `HelpFormatter` class that creates the help.  It get's most of the necessary information from the `Action` class objects  created with the `add_argument` method.  See the `argparse.py` file for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no builtin for this, but if your params are only simple values something like the following might suffice:

```
nextflow.enable.dsl=2


params.publish_dir = System.getenv('TMPDIR') ?: './results'
params.publish_mode = 'copy'

check_params()


workflow {
    
    // your awesome workflow here
}

def check_params() {

    if( params.remove('help') ) {
        params.each{ k, v -> println "params.${k.padRight(25)} = ${v}" }
        exit 0
    }

    // additional validation here
}
```

```
$ nextflow run main.nf --help
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `main.nf` [gigantic_plateau] - revision: c61c697636
params.publish_dir               = /tmp
params.publish_mode              = copy
```

Note that publishing results to a temporary directory usually doesn't make much sense.